# How can I make dependent variables respond and update in HTML/javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I was hoping someone could help me out.  I am modelling a (simple) nuclear reactor and have a number of variables which are dependent on other variables, and on user inputs.

In the below code, initially the Control Rod Height is set at 50%, but the user can move the control rods up and down in the limits of 0 to 100.  Reactor temperature is directly dependent on the control rod height, but I can't get it to update.

The TEST button displays the updated Control Rod Height, but the TEMPERATURE button will only ever display the initial value (based on control rod height = 50).

Is it possible to make Reactor Temperature update as the user changes the height of the control rods?

Thank you!

HTML

```
<div id="game">
<button onClick = "IncCRH()">Increase Control Rod Height</button>
<button onClick = "DecCRH()">Decrease Control Rod Height</button>
<div id="result"></div>
<br>
<br>
<button onClick="test()">TEST</button>
<br>
<br>
<button onClick="ReacTemp()">TEMPERATURE</button>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var ControlRodHeight = 50;
var ReactorTemperature = (250 + (ControlRodHeight*20));

function IncCRH(){
    user = ++ControlRodHeight;
    if (ControlRodHeight > 100)
    ControlRodHeight = 100;
}
function DecCRH() {
    user = --ControlRodHeight;
    if (ControlRodHeight < 0)
    ControlRodHeight = 0
}

function test(){
    alert (ControlRodHeight);
}

function ReacTemp(){
    alert (ReactorTemperature);
}
```

Comment: The concept of a variable 'binding' is not native to JavaScript. You need to manually update the reactor temperature each time the control rod height changes. Or better, compute the reactor temperature just when it is needed, i.e. when you call `ReacTemp()`. And even better: write a function `getReacTemp(controlRodHeight)` which encapsulates the computation of the reactor temperature: `getReactorTemperature = ControlRodHeight => 250 + (ControlRodHeight*20);`.

Comment: Ah I didn't realise that, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manually recalculate the ReactorTemperature when you change ControlRodHeight:

```
function IncCRH(){
    user = ++ControlRodHeight;
    if (ControlRodHeight > 100) {
        ControlRodHeight = 100;
    }
    ReactorTemperature = (250 + (ControlRodHeight*20));
}
```

(Or call a function which is doing it, in order to not repeat the code.)

Answer (score 0):

you need to change ReactorTemperature  value in these functions to have updated value
var ControlRodHeight = 50;
    var ReactorTemperature = (250 + (ControlRodHeight*20));

```
function IncCRH(){
    user = ++ControlRodHeight;
    if (ControlRodHeight > 100){
    ControlRodHeight = 100;
}
    ReactorTemperature = (250 + (ControlRodHeight*20));
}
function DecCRH() {
    user = --ControlRodHeight;
    if (ControlRodHeight < 0){
    ControlRodHeight = 0
}
ReactorTemperature = (250 + (ControlRodHeight*20));
}
```